# How do I find out what is disabling my WPF button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a legacy WPF client and I have a list of items, each of the items being displayed in a custom control. The control contains a button for removing that item from the list.

When I add an item to the list, something calls `.IsEnabled = false` on the button. I can't find anything that directly calls this. I tried misusing the event handler to set `IsEnabled` back to `true`, like this:

```
private void ButtonRemove_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        buttonRemove.IsEnabledChanged -= ButtonRemove_IsEnabledChanged;
        buttonRemove.IsEnabled = true;
        buttonRemove.IsEnabledChanged += ButtonRemove_IsEnabledChanged;
    }
}
```

but that doesn't change anything. The call stack only shows `Main()`, `startUp()`, and 'External Code': [image: call stack]

I have no idea how to figure out what is disabling my button. Any ideas on how to track down what is causing this?

### Edit:

I wanted to inquire about debugging techniques to use because the backend code is stupidly convoluted and I didn't want to offload the actual work on stackoverflow, since that would require posting dozens if not hundreds of files here.

Comment: can it be the Command bound to the button?

Comment: @ASh the button has no bindings. at least I think so, maybe I misunderstand. I am not very well versed with proper WPF. I see no `Binding` in the xaml anyway

Comment: If you could post the XAML for the control in context with any associated styles that may help shed some light on the origin of the change.   If the changes occur in style or data triggers it can be tricky to find root cause, similar to CSS for web.

Comment: You've not shown us anywhere near a minimal viable reproduction so your question is likely to get closed.  What list of what where?  How does the button get to invoke some code when you click it?  Somewhere you have that that button in xaml or code. What happens if you explicitly set isenabled to true on it?

Comment: What about the parent of that button? If it's also disabled then the button's `IsEnabled` will be forced to be `False`

Comment: Could it be that your basic Button style is overwritten globally somewhere else?

Comment: @DavidGlass I honestly have no idea where styles would be registered, but there is some kind of global styling going on. Seeing that all other buttons are affected by the visual changes, but not constantly disabled, I'd assume it doesn't have to do with that. I'm happy to be corrected if I am wrong on this.

Comment: See if various `Getxxx` methods in [BindingOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingoperations?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) will return you any binding.

Comment: @Andy I meant to keep it vague, because I don't want you to solve my problem. I want to learn how to properly track down issues like that on my own. Do you want me to explain our whole data model? This is showing data from articles and their condition and listing data. It is shown on the listing page, in a list that shows the articles of a shipment. The button invokes code by it's `IsEnabled`-property changing, like the name of the method suggests. Having the property set in XAML doesn't change anything, either.

Comment: @Khiro good call, worth checking out

Comment: The stack trace is very unhelpful, fix it with Tools > Options > Debugging > General, untick "Enable Just My Code".

Comment: The XAML control can reference a style directly (Style=...), or the style can be embedded in control itself, or inherited by parent.  The key point is the XAML may easily reveal a style and styles can have triggers as well as data bindings that can have an effect on the UI.  The XAML files all generate intermediate files in obj\debug directory: <xamlfile>.g.cs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your button is not disabled and it doesn't work just because it is placed under a grid or border, although it is visible, by clicking on it, you are actually clicking on the grid.
This happened to me!
Or maybe the parent container is disabled!

Comment: nice heads up, but the button is greyed out